# Bayes' Theorem for Probability Distribution Functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, bayes-theorem

I'm working on an application of Bayesian inference. I'm familiar with Bayes' theorem expressed in terms of the probabilities of events, i.e.
$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)} \propto P(B|A)P(A)$$
for some events $A$ and $B$. I also understand that in Bayesian inference, this is typically expressed in terms of probability distribution functions, i.e. for some unknown parameter $\theta$ and some data vector $x$,
$$f(\theta|x) = \frac{f(x|\theta)f(\theta)}{f(x)} \propto f(x|\theta)f(\theta).$$

I can just use the formula above and do what I need to do with it, but I'd like to understand where it comes from, particularly since that will help me avoid mistakes in applying it. I assume that the latter equation is derived from the former (since the former is simple and can be readily derived from first principles), but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to go from one to the other. Google has been entirely unhelpful. Would someone be willing to explain where the latter equation comes from, or point me toward a resource?

Comment: The first is the definition of conditional probability, the second is the definition of conditional density.  I don't understand the proportionalities though. The "constant" of proportionality is, clearly a function of $B$ (or of $x$), so what claim is being made here?

Comment: Thank you! Apparently conditional density was what I needed to google. I had been trying to google variations on "bayes theorem probability density function" and getting nothing. The reason it's considered a constant of proportionality is that in Bayesian inference, we only care about $A$ or $\theta$, so anything only dependent on $B$ or $x$ is considered a constant.

I have one follow-up question, but I'll edit my original question for that.

Comment: Never mind, I think I answered my own follow-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @lulu who commented on my question -- apparently I just needed to google the definition of conditional probability density functions. Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution), conditional density is defined as
$$f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x, y)}{f_X(x)}$$
and since $f_{X,Y}(x, y) = f_{Y,X}(y, x)$, the latter equation pops right out as
$$f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_X(x) = f_{X,Y}(x, y) = f_{X|Y}(x|y)f_Y(y).$$